# Java application font size

Tags: configuration, java, gui, interface

I have downloaded a Java program with a GUI. I do not have its source.

I am wondering if there is a general Java configuration to change font size in all programs (or, even better, in this one program)

This program seems to be made with Swing

Comment: if it is of any use, the program is from the Brasil's IRS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lot of details are missing here. I couldn't find a link for it online which would have answered many questions. But on a general note, unless application specifically exposes an option inside its configuration file or as a commandline option for font, you cannot set a font size for the entire app. IMO, look inside a user manual that should tell you how to achieve this.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.60%2Fdiag%2Fappendixes%2Fenv_var%2Fenv_jvm.html

Link above talks about specifying a directory of fonts that will be avaliable to the application. Mind you that link talks about IBM JVM and not Oracle JVM( Formerly Sun JVM)

http://www.herongyang.com/JVM/System-Get-and-Add-System-Property.html

This link listed all the available system properties for java command and font isn't one of them.

This question should be posted on StackOverFlow for more exposure and more precise answer.

Comment: (http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoafisica/irpf/2012/declaracao/download-programas.htm)
This is the program. I did not think to link it, since I assumed there was a general configuration, and I just had not found it.
I'll post it to stackoverflow. What other information should I add to make the question precise enough ?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't read portugese, but a look at the read_me file showed me this.

    "To use the program PIT 2012, requires that the monitor is set to 1024 x 768 pixels or larger and small fonts."

I looked at the exec.sh, there are no options other than help. 

Try `java -jar irpf.jar --help`. 

Also try searching for `são` inside the help file. It seems to show some results, I just can't read them. 

Java does not honor system look and feel, so even if you change your computer's font to be bigger, it will not affect you application. Basically modifying the code is your only way to go at this point.